# Поиск комментариев в стиле С

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash

Необходимо найти и распечатать все комментарии вида `//` и `/**/` , которые есть в файле new.

Как искать коммментарии вида `//`, если два слеша располагаются не в начале строки?
И почему команда:

```
egrep "^\/\*(.|\n)*\*\/" new
```

не позволяет найти комментарий, разбитый на несколько строк?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рассмотрим тестовый файл **test**:

```
abc //comment 1
def
aaa /* long
comment
again
*/
//comment2
```

Для обоих случаев потребуется `grep` с GNU-расширениями, а именно, с возможностью использования PERL-регексов. Он должен поддерживать ключи `-P` и `-o`.

---

### Поиск `// ...`

```
grep -oP '\/\/\s*\K.*' test
```

`\K` используется для объявления блока `\/\/\s*` как look-behind assertion, что позволяет убрать **//** из выдачи.

Результат:

```
comment 1
comment2
```

---

### Поиск `/* ... */`

```
grep -oPz '(?s)\/\*\s*\K.*?(?=\s*\*\/)' test
```

Опция `-z` представляет файл в виде набора строк с символами новой строки замененными на \0 байты

`(?s)` - DOTALL модификатор, позволяющий `.` в регекс находить символы новой строки

`\K` и `(?= )` - look-ahead и look-behind блоки, для исключения символов **/* */** из вывода.

Результат:

```
long
comment
again
```

---

### Поиск всего вместе

Вот вариант поиска всех комментариев сразу, с сохранением символов комментариев.

```
grep -oPz '(?s)(\/\*\s*.*?\s*\*\/)|(\/\/\s*.*?$)' test
```

Здесь убраны look-ahead и look-behind блоки.

Добавлена конструкция `( )|( )`, позволяющая использование двух шаблонов.

`.*?$` - не жадный поиск до конца строки

Результат:

```
//comment 1
/* long
comment
again
*/
//comment2
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!